# Need for software solution to set expiry dates for requests

Tags: date, lotus

I have to create a program that would allow different users to post a request (there should be a request form to fill in) that would be then moderated by an administrator. The administrator then would have to set different expiry dates, multiple ones for a single request, and should be able to review the incoming expiry dates. The administrator should be also able to edit those already accepted requests and change dates, add comments, etc.

It would be nice if the users could be informed by email of the changes made by the admin to their request.

I would like to know from you what would be the easiest and most economical way of achieving this goal. I have IBM lotus available and would be glad if I could use it as mainframe for the app, but have no knowledge in administrating or coding for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/cs-pt1/
and
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cs_schema_toc

So the concept should be to make an app that uses the LOTUS CALENDAR api to add events or modify them. 
With comments and attachments.

Gues the best corse of action would be any programming language you are comftable with since the learning curve for the api should be way less intensive then learning a new programming language.